# Pyspark : Dynamically prepare pyspark-sql query using parameters

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What are the different ways to dynamicaly bind parameters and prepare pyspark-sql statament.

Example:

**Dynamic Query**

```
query = '''SELECT column1, column2
           FROM ${db_name}.${table_name}
           WHERE column1 = ${filter_value}'''
```

Above dynamic query have ${db_name}, ${table_name} and ${filter_value} variables, These variables will get values from run time parameters.

**Parameter Details:**

```
db_name = 'your_db_name'
table_name = 'your_table_name'
filter_value = 'some_value'
```

**Expected Query after Binding Parameters in Dynamic Query**

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM your_db_name.your_table_name
WHERE column1 = some_value
```

Comment: Is it for `Spark-jdbc` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are few options to prepare pyspark-sql through binding parameter.

***Option#1*** - Using String Interpolation / f-Strings (Python 3.6+)

```
db_name = 'your_db_name'
table_name = 'your_table_name'
filter_value = 'some_value'

query = f'''SELECT column1, column2
           FROM {db_name}.{table_name}
           WHERE column1 = {filter_value}'''
```

***Option#2*** - Using String Formatting (str.format)

```
query = '''SELECT column1, column2
           FROM {}.{}
           WHERE column1 = {}'''

db_name = 'your_db_name'
table_name = 'your_table_name'
filter_value = 'some_value'

query.format(db_name, table_name, filter_value)
```

***Option#3*** - Using Template String

```
query = '''SELECT column1, column2
           FROM ${db_name}.${table_name}
           WHERE column1 = ${filter_value}'''

db_name = 'your_db_name'
table_name = 'your_table_name'
filter_value = 'some_value'

from string import Template
t = Template(query)
t.substitute(db_name=db_name, table_name=table_name, filter_value=filter_value)
```

- String Interpolation/f-Strings (***Option#1***) is recommended if you have
  python 3.6+ else use String Formatting str.format (***Option#2***)
- Template    String are more useful to handle user supplied string
  (***Option#3***)

Comment: Isn't Option #2 prone to SQL-Injection and avoidable?

Comment: All three options just use plain string interpolation without proper escaping. All three options are potential SQL injection vulnerabilities. When any of the variables can be defined by the user, they might be able to retrieve data they are not supposed to see.